# Are involuntary commitment hearings under the NYS Mental Hygiene Law heard in the county or city court?

Tags: new-york-state, court, mental-health

All in the title, unfortunately. Under the mental hygiene law one is entitled to a hearing following a 2-physician certification of involuntary treatment worthiness. What type of court is this type of proceeding heard in?

Comment: Not city court. Probably the NYS Supreme Court which is the trial court of general jurisdiction. NYS MHL Guardianships under § 81 are in county court. I could imagine Surrogate's Court having concurrent jurisdiction but haven't seen any positive evidence of that. Harder to track down than I expected. I'll research with better authority before I answer.

Comment: No from memory I recall it being in the building of the county courthouse in white plains.

Comment: A county court house building often has more than one court in its in NYS's byzantine court system.